# Disable keyboard-shortcuts in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anybody know how can I programmatically  disable the keyboard-shortcuts in IE?

For example, i have a textbox in my web page, with its value taken from a barcode reader. But the barcode contains the sequence <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> opens the IE feeds and Enter opens the selected feed in the browser, so this is a serious problem for me.

And if it's impossible to do this programmatically, is there a way that the client could resolve this from the browser's options, win registries, anything?

Answer (score 0):

Can you accept the data in a pop up window?  I'm thinking that if you open a popup window without all the chrome around it, the shortcut keys won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this issue can be worked around in Firefox](http://www.mozdev.org/drupal/forum/How-disable-CTRLJ-firefox-shortcut-using-javascript-funcions), is firefox a possibility for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an ActiveX Control that contains the text box and talks to the scanner.  Implement `IInputObject::TranslateAcceleratorIO()` and say no.

My question is why does your barcode contain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>?! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was also confused about the barcodes having such values. It seems that only one barcode from the bunch they tested had this type of strange characters.

Comment: Its a character set issue. The character number that the barcode translates to is mapping to the Ctrl and Shift keys in the current Windows locale. I can think of a few situations where this might happen. International barcodes or bad barcodes. Depending on the format of the linear barcodes being scanned, there is a checksum digit that is usually added to the end of the barcode to help detect bad scans.
http://omniplanar.com/links/articles/maximizing-bar-code-performance-a-look-at-error-correction.html